# writing a generic stack class in c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, generics, inheritance

Hi i ma not sure if my code is incorrect i been searchin can find anything.

here is the question :

Write a generic class, named Stack, in Java or C++ for the stack type that uses a linked list
to store the elements. The Stack class has a member variable, named head, that references the
first node of the list, and a member variable, named size, that stores the number of elements
on the stack. The Stack class provides all of the methods of the STL stack class, including
push, pop, top, and empty.

they give node class

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
public:
T nodeValue;
Node<T> *next;
Node (const T& item, Node<T> *ptr = NULL):
nodeValue(item), next(ptr)
{}
};
```

Now this is the Stack class i wrote:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack:public std::stack<Node>
{
public:
    Node<T> *head;
    T size;
    Stack(const T& capacity, Node<T> *ptr):size(capacity),head(ptr){};
};
```

when i run it i get this :

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Sequence> class std::stack’
```

Comment: You haven't told us what's wrong. Do you have an error message? Also worth noting that if this is a homework assignment they almost certainly don't want you to use `std::stack`.

Comment: What's the purpose writing your own stack class instead of using the STL implementation? What's your error in detail? Unclear what you're asking for!

Comment: I doubt they intended for you to inherit from `std::stack` when they asked this question. Also, you shouldn't be inheriting from standard library containers, as they don't have virtual destructors.

Comment: You could have stopped with a template alias if this is what you were going to do (and be glad you did this here, since I don't think this was what your prof had in mind). They want you to *implement* `std::stack<>`; not *utilize* it.

Comment: sorry guides i does not compile i get this error:

    error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter     list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Sequence> class std::stack’
 class Stack:public std::stack<Node>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you should instantiate `Node`, when you're using it with `std::stack`:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack : public std::stack<Node<T> >
                                 // ^^^
{
];
```